# create table in mysql issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create table in mysql with name `customer_wallet`. I am getting error like this table is already exist. I can not see that table in `phpmyadmin`.

I tried to DROP table,

```
drop table customer_wallet;
```

And I am getting error:

```
#1051 - Unknown table 'customer_wallet'
```

Why is it like this? Is that table hidden somewhere?

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the correct database?

Comment: Yes. Everything is correct.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't deleted? See if its still in your database, but that would be an error that would come up if it was deleted already.

Comment: That's why I tried by dropping the table. But, it's giving me error as unknown table.

Comment: Run a "Show tables;" in your database and see if its there.

Comment: Oh okay i see. Can you make a table under a different name?

Comment: Under different name, it's creating. but in my application I used old name. Then I tried change table name. But, it's not letting me to change table name as wel.

Comment: You have referenced to some other table in (say foreign key) in customer wallet and have dropped the base table. This is usually error 1051.

Comment: @RyanBrady: there is no `customer_wallet` table in `SHOW TABLES` command.

Comment: @Abhi: Yes. Actually, I have referenced customer id with customers table. How can I resolve this issue now?

Comment: see if you have a view named customer_wallet.
select TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where TABLE_TYPE like 'VIEW';

Comment: @Len_D: There is no view in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Goto mysql prompt and use `drop table` to delete the specified table.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once. I solved it by deleting the table file from the database folder in programData/Mysql/.../data/your-database-folder/table file

Comment: From where I can access this folder? I am running my application on windows azure with clearDB.

Comment: I have not used azure, but if you have root access to the server you can find it in ProgramData/Mysql/.../data/your-database-folder/table file